# updating a user in Angular 1

Tags: angularjs

I have to make a school exercise where i need to update a users information in the data base the edit field works in a modal and needs to immediately display the updated user information.

what angular functions do i need i have been reading the documentation but can't find what i need.

```
userFactory.editUser(vm.user).then(success, failure);
  function success() {
    vm.user.push(user);
  }

  function failure(error) {
    vm.errorMessage = error;
  }

  $uibModalInstance.close(vm.user);
};
```

This is what I tried but it did not work.

Comment: It should be `function success(user) {
    vm.user.push(user);
  }`

Comment: thank you this worked :)

Comment: glad that helped! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

success function should have a parameter `user`.

it should be-

```
function success(user) {
    vm.user.push(user);
}
```